# Only find one match in a specific location in a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to process a large build log looking for copy operations going to the wrong place. I'm just using Notepad++.

If I have a string like this:

> Line 25672:     Creating hard link to copy C:\DevDir\DERP\Output\x64\Release\someBin.dll to C:\DevDir\not\good\path\here\someBin.dll

and this

> Line 25673:     Creating hard link to copy C:\DevDir\not\good\path\here\someBin.dll to C:\DevDir\DERP\Output\x64\Release\someBin.dll

The special word here is `DERP` to look for. Basically, I need to see when something in `DERP` is being copied to a non-DERP location, and when a non-DERP location is copying to a DERP location.

So I need to find:

> `\scopy\s`, then `DERP`, then `\sto\s`, then NOT `DERP` to end of line
>
> `\scopy\s`, then NOT `DERP`, then `\sto\s`, then `DERP` to end of line

I've tried a couple variations of this to get the first one working. I thought I had the second working when swapping the negative lookaheads, but after manually scrolling through the aggregated results, I saw I was getting `DERP` on the incorrect side of `to`.

`^.*? copy .*?DERP.*? to (?!DERP).*$`

I can't use an answer the determines from solely the frequency of `DERP` as relative paths may cause one side of `to` to have multiple `DERP`s. This relative path clause is where I'm having trouble accounting to.

EDIT:

Hm... did some tinkering and this is looking promising:

`(^.*? copy )(?>(?:(?!DERP).)*? to).*?DERP.*?$`

Comment: Could you split the line on 'to' then check for matches of DERP on the two substrings?

Comment: Do you mean 'split' with `\K` or something else? Please keep in mind this is for Notepad++, per the tag/description. I don't see why that wouldn't work, personally, but the goal is to capture the whole string, meaning this could get ugly... I won't stop you though!

Comment: if you use `(?!DERP)` in your regex instead of `(?!\\DERP\\)` you will also not match `path\to\notDERP\file.bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, to find DERP and then not DERP:

`(^.*? copy ).*?DERP.*? to (?>(?:(?!DERP).)*?$)`

To find not DERP and then to find DERP:

`(^.*? copy )(?>(?:(?!DERP).)*? to).*?DERP.*?$`

So I guess the answer here is using this type of nesting:

`(?>(?:(?!ThingToNotFind).))*?SomethingToFind`

If there's a more elegant way to write or articulate this in general terms, I'll accept that answer. While I can use and modify this, I have a hard time looking at these nested patterns and groking them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should also use the path delimiters around `DERP` to make sure you are really looking at complete folder names.

### Solution I

This follows the regex supposed by the edit of the question:

`((^.*? copy )(?>(?:(?!DERP).)*? to).*?DERP.*?$|(^.*? copy ).*?(DERP).*? to (?>(?:(?!DERP).)*$))`

Check out the playground: https://regex101.com/r/hX9aR4/1

### Solution II

NOTEPAD++ supports capture groups. I would therefore use this to get all the erroneous copying.

Find: `(?:^(?:(?!\\DERP\\).)*$)|(?:^.* copy .*?(?:\\DERP\\).* to .*(?:\\DERP\\).*$)|(^.* copy .*\\DERP\\.*$)|(?:^.*$)`

Replace: `\1`

### Explanatoin

`(?:^(?:(?!\\DERP\\).)*$)` this matches lines not containing "\DERP\", but does not capture them.

`(?:^.* copy .*?(?:\\DERP\\).* to .*(?:\\DERP\\).*$)` matches every log of a coppy from DERP to another DERP, but does not capture it.

Then `(^.* copy .*\\DERP\\.*$)` **matches and captures** lines with one or more DERP folders, but since we already got rid of those with two or more in the first expression, we should be safe.

Then `(?:^.*$)` matches all the other lines with a non capturing expression so they are replaced by nothing, as is the first non capturing part.

Check out the playground: https://regex101.com/r/nJ9iC4/3

Comment: Just an FYI -- you need to use $1 instead of \1, as this is a Notepad++ question.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck Notepad++ works just fine with \1. However there is more fun stuff one can do with the $ notation. See: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions